# Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin by sending request to flask

Tags: get, flask, cross-domain

I am sending GET request from localhost:8000 to flask :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:5000/test/", function() {
    }).done(function() {
            document.location = "http://localhost:5000";
            }).fail(function() {
            console.log("server not ready.");
            });
        });
});
```

and in `"server.py"` I am handling GET like:

```
import app

@server.route('/test/',methods = ['GET'])
def test():
    print "in test status check"
    return jsonify({'status':'OK'})
```

However I am getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:**5000**/test/. Origin http://127.0.0.1:**8000** is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flask you can create custom decorator to control Access Origin Policy. This article may help you: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/

Code from article:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import make_response, request, current_app
from functools import update_wrapper


def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None,
                max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True,
                automatic_options=True):
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
        origin = ', '.join(origin)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
                resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers

            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator
```

And here is how you can use it:

```
@app.route('/my_service')
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def my_service():
    return jsonify(foo='cross domain ftw')
```